# How I add JS file from Java code in JSF?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I need add a JS file from java code as outputScript tag.

I can add scripts using ResponseWriter, but not avoid duplicate files and can't set head as target.

Answer (score 1):

Auto answer.

I used @ResourceDependencies and work fine:

```
@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(name="myfile.js", library="js", target="head")
})
public class MyClass {

}
```